# I have a NodeJS backend I am developing to work alongside a ReactJS frontend but I keep getting a 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, backend

I am testing my NodeJS backend using Insomnia and while it does work no problem in Insomnia I am getting a 500 error on the frontend every time. I was wondering if anyone maybe knew where this could be coming from if like I said it works just fine on my the endpoint testing program. Since it is a 500 error it is not very descriptive. Links can be shared if needed

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log("cred username", creds.username);
axios
  .post("https://exampleapi/api/login")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
    localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.access_token);
    props.history.push("/");
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err.response)); };
```

Comment: post the code what you have tried.

Comment: 5XX are server errors, please post the code

Comment: Add the console/terminal error message.

Comment: log the request you are sending to your API and then test the API with the same request separately, also implement better error handling.

Comment: `post("exampleapi/api/login")` post request with no `body`?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out it was an error in my post request would should have been included was

```
  const handleSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log("cred username", creds.username);
axios
  .post("https://mystery-doggo.herokuapp.com/api/login", creds)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
    localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.payload);
    props.history.push("/");
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err.response));
```

};

"creds" after the link and change res.data.access_token to res.data.payload

Comment: Can you give me your example data login to your site: `https://mystery-doggo.herokuapp.com/api/login` or your problem has been resolved.